# May I ask for help to a project?

Tags: discussion, support

If I want to program a large game, may I ask for help for the project? May I ask for others who want to program it with me?

Comment: If you're looking for **payed** developers you can check http://careers.stackoverflow.com. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 12):

No, Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems that you have.

You might be able to find someone in a chat room to work with you, though. (In fact, I'm currently collaborating with a few users [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12239/the-ascii-collab-club) on some ASCII art games!)

Answer (score 3):

If you run a popular or very interesting **open source** game development effort, you can [nominate it to receive free advertising on StackOverflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). But it's a popularity contest based on votes, so if no-one has heard of your project don't be surprised if you don't win the contest.